# Why is my app slow after deploying on heroku

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, socket.io, web-deployment

So I wrote a quick app [Collaborative drawing board](https://github.com/dbajpeyi/drawingboard) using `socket.io` and `nodejs`

Works really well locally.

However , as I deployed it on heroku [here](http://warm-fortress-1340.herokuapp.com/), it has suddenly become very slow.

Can someone explain why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it's due to the delay imposed by using Heroku's servers as a middle-man for your requests. Does Heroku have other servers which are closer to you which you could use?